# Installing Experience Builder in Offline Environment - Errors

Tags: offline, node-js, arcgis-experience-builder

I have followed the instructions provided by esri at this link, but I cannot get the Experience Builder to install properly in our offline DEV environment.
[image]

https://developers.arcgis.com/experience-builder/guide/install-guide/#offline-install

I have tried 3 different versions of Node JS and received the same errors.

```
 PS C:\ArcGISExperienceBuilder\client> npm install --offline
npm WARN exb-client@1.7.0 No description
npm WARN exb-client@1.7.0 No repository field.
npm WARN exb-client@1.7.0 No license field.

npm ERR! code ENOTCACHED
npm ERR! request to https://registry.npmjs.org/json-schema/-/json-schema-0.4.0.tgz failed: cach
' but no cached response available.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\morij\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2022-01-20T14_39_48_321Z-debug.log
PS C:\ArcGISExperienceBuilder\client>
```

I am at a loss currently as to what my next step should be, I also attached the log file referenced above to the question here https://pastebin.com/c7B5pEvS

Comment: You can confirm you got steps 4-7 on the guide done correctly? Download, extract, config and copy?

Comment: @KHibma yes, even tried on 2 different dev machines